Adding specific domain for safari web extension
I am writing a safari web extension at the moment in Xcode. I want tab a button inside my popup window which than calls the firebase firestore database to get some data. Therefore I want to include the firestore library in my popup.js script with import { initializeApp, getFirestore, collection } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-firestore.js'
But as I am doing this I get the error
Refused to load https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-firestore.js because it does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy. even tho I have this specific link inside my manifest and in my info.plist file.
This is my info.plist file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SFSafariToolbarItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>SFToolbarItemClassName</key>
                <string>ViewController</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.Safari.web-extension</string>
        <key>content-security-policy</key>
        <string>default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-firestore.js;</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

And this is my manifest file
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "default_locale": "en",

    "name": "__MSG_extension_name__",
    "description": "__MSG_extension_description__",
    "version": "1.0",

    "icons": {
        "48": "images/icon-48.png",
        "96": "images/icon-96.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png",
        "256": "images/icon-256.png",
        "512": "images/icon-512.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": "background.js"
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": [ "content.js" ],
        "matches": [ "*://example.com/*" ]
    }],

    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/toolbar-icon-16.png",
            "19": "images/toolbar-icon-19.png",
            "32": "images/toolbar-icon-32.png",
            "38": "images/toolbar-icon-38.png",
            "48": "images/toolbar-icon-48.png",
            "72": "images/toolbar-icon-72.png"
        }
    },

    "permissions": [ "nativeMessaging", "activeTab", "tabs" ],
    
    "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-firestore.js; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
      }
}

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong and what the correct way of implementing this domain is?
